# Ошибка PermissionError: при открытии файла на запись в Program Files

Tags: python, логирование

Помогите, выдает ошибку permissionerror хоть всё вроде бы есть и записано всё правильно. Сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyTake\PyTake.py", line 46, in <module>
    ptCallRequestsTroune.__callRequestsMode__()
  File "C:\PyTake\ptCallRequestsTroune.py", line 20, in __callRequestsMode__
    ptRequestsTroune.__requestsMode__()
  File "C:\PyTake\ptRequestsTroune.py", line 33, in __requestsMode__
    ptDefaultCommandsTroune.__procStandartHide__()
  File "C:\PyTake\ptDefaultCommandsTroune.py", line 50, in __procStandartHide__
    logIdentify = open("C:\\Program Files\\PyTake v.1.0\\log\\MAIN_LOG.log", 'a')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\PyTake v.1.0\\log\\MAIN_LOG.log'
```

Директория есть, файлы есть. Почему записывать не хочет??

[image: Все верно]

Comment: Права на запись есть в этот файл? Возможно нужно интерпретатор запускать от имениадминистратора, не смотря даже на то, что работаете под админом

Comment: @demol0cv Да не, раньше нормально работал, сейчас не хочет, не знаю почему, может что-то лишнего добавил

Comment: проверить всёже стоит, например выполнить скрипт из консольки запущенной от админа

Comment: @demol0cv хм... Заработало!) Моя ленивость просто убила меня)) Вот только я не пойму, раньше без администратора записывало, теперь хочет админа. Кстати не подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтоб всегда запускала от Админа. Ибо сейчас компилирую и надо чтоб всё работало правильно, и записывало куда надо. Без всяких отказов в доступе. Буду благодарен если дадите ответ!

Comment: runas /savecred /noprofile /useradmin@pcname "cmd /C python.exe" как-то так. Копайте в сторону команды runas. Один раз запросит пароль админа и всё. Вообще лучше не писать в C:\Program Files тогда и не будет таких проблем

Comment: @demol0cv я тоже так подумал, и перенес в c:\ там не требует прав администратора, но я создаю инсталятор и у меня вопрос про стандартное изменение пути к файлу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606409/cx-freeze-msi-installer-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8 Если знаете хоть что , то дайте ответ буду благодарен!

Comment: @EvleapsCorp. просто не пишите лог в Program Files. Используйте, например, %APPDATA% или %TEMP% для этого.

Comment: @EvleapsCorp. оформлю как ответ

Answer (score 2):

Windows требует повышения прав пользователя если происходит обращение в недоступные для записи обычному пользователю места (в данном случае C:\Program Files).

Что-бы избежать этого необходимо запускать скрипт с повышенными привилегиями (не смотря на то что вы уже администратор), например из консоли запущенной "От имени администратора"